# Why does Framer Motion Animation does not work in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, next.js, framer-motion

I 'm trying to rotate a part of a SVG using framer motion library i my Next.js project.(https://www.framer.com/motion/). But it doesn't animate in that project. I created a react project and and tested same svg code. In there it's animation works as expected. I need to find why its not working in Next.js.

This is the SVG componentcode.

```
"use client";
import * as React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const SvgComponent = (props) => (
  <svg
    width={1138}
    height={1138}
    viewBox="0 0 1138 1138"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    {...props}
  >
    <path
      d="M778.232 378.816C673.667 263.234 495.203 254.303 379.621 358.867C264.039 463.432 255.108 641.896 359.672 757.478C464.237 873.06 642.701 881.991 758.283 777.427C873.865 672.862 882.796 494.398 778.232 378.816Z"
      fill="url(#paint0_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      d="M867.367 299.074C718.291 134.29 463.857 121.557 299.074 270.633C134.29 419.709 121.557 674.143 270.633 838.926C419.709 1003.71 674.143 1016.44 838.926 867.367C1003.71 718.291 1016.44 463.857 867.367 299.074Z"
      stroke="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M778.196 379.276C673.797 263.877 495.615 254.96 380.215 359.359C264.816 463.759 255.899 641.94 360.298 757.34C464.697 872.739 642.879 881.656 758.279 777.257C873.678 672.857 882.595 494.675 778.196 379.276Z"
      stroke="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M733.607 420.475C651.546 329.767 511.49 322.758 420.783 404.819C330.075 486.88 323.066 626.936 405.127 717.643C487.188 808.351 627.244 815.36 717.951 733.299C808.659 651.238 815.668 511.182 733.607 420.475Z"
      stroke="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M689.021 461.672C629.298 395.657 527.368 390.556 461.353 450.278C395.338 510.001 390.237 611.931 449.959 677.946C509.682 743.961 611.612 749.062 677.627 689.34C743.642 629.617 748.743 527.687 689.021 461.672Z"
      stroke="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M643.337 500.677C605.953 459.354 542.148 456.161 500.825 493.545C459.502 530.929 456.309 594.734 493.693 636.057C531.077 677.38 594.882 680.573 636.205 643.189C677.528 605.805 680.721 542 643.337 500.677Z"
      stroke="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M598.751 541.875C583.705 525.244 558.026 523.959 541.396 539.004C524.765 554.05 523.48 579.729 538.525 596.359C553.571 612.99 579.25 614.275 595.88 599.23C612.511 584.184 613.796 558.505 598.751 541.875Z"
      stroke="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M706.071 488.042C704.148 490.741 704.778 494.487 707.478 496.409C710.177 498.332 713.923 497.702 715.845 495.002C717.768 492.303 717.138 488.557 714.438 486.635C711.739 484.712 707.993 485.342 706.071 488.042Z"
      fill="url(#paint1_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      d="M313.36 703.292C308.076 710.712 309.808 721.01 317.228 726.294C324.648 731.578 334.946 729.846 340.23 722.426C345.514 715.006 343.782 704.708 336.362 699.424C328.942 694.14 318.644 695.872 313.36 703.292Z"
      fill="url(#paint2_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      d="M167.567 670.193C162.283 677.613 164.015 687.911 171.435 693.195C178.855 698.479 189.153 696.747 194.437 689.327C199.721 681.907 197.989 671.609 190.569 666.325C183.149 661.041 172.851 662.773 167.567 670.193Z"
      fill="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M673.567 240.193C668.283 247.613 670.015 257.911 677.435 263.195C684.855 268.479 695.153 266.747 700.437 259.327C705.721 251.907 703.989 241.609 696.569 236.325C689.149 231.041 678.851 232.773 673.567 240.193Z"
      fill="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M779.221 606.089C776.338 610.138 777.283 615.758 781.331 618.641C785.38 621.524 791 620.579 793.883 616.531C796.766 612.482 795.821 606.862 791.773 603.979C787.724 601.096 782.104 602.041 779.221 606.089Z"
      fill="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M410.009 522.578C408.113 525.24 408.735 528.934 411.397 530.83C414.059 532.726 417.753 532.104 419.649 529.442C421.545 526.78 420.923 523.086 418.261 521.19C415.599 519.294 411.905 519.916 410.009 522.578Z"
      fill="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M408.721 407.377C406.639 410.301 407.321 414.359 410.246 416.442C413.17 418.524 417.228 417.842 419.311 414.917C421.393 411.993 420.711 407.935 417.786 405.852C414.862 403.77 410.804 404.452 408.721 407.377Z"
      fill="#E1E4ED"
    />
    <path
      d="M420.221 189.089C417.338 193.138 418.283 198.758 422.331 201.641C426.38 204.524 432 203.579 434.883 199.531C437.766 195.482 436.821 189.862 432.773 186.979C428.724 184.096 423.104 185.041 420.221 189.089Z"
      fill="url(#paint3_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path d="M800 272.758H247V823.758H800V272.758Z" fill="url(#pattern0)" />
    <path
      opacity={0.6}
      d="M691.38 400.173L696.185 536.99C696.379 542.415 700.84 546.722 706.271 546.722H942.21C947.686 546.722 952.162 542.355 952.296 536.885L955.594 398.474C955.728 392.78 951.132 388.116 945.433 388.145L701.392 389.74C695.707 389.785 691.171 394.494 691.365 400.173H691.38Z"
      fill="#36D1F7"
    />

    <path
      style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}
      opacity={0.6}
      d="M691.738 407.148H955.325L955.742 399.934C956.115 393.556 951.013 388.19 944.612 388.235L700.661 390.157C695.573 390.202 691.484 394.39 691.589 399.472L691.738 407.148Z"
      fill="url(#paint4_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}
      opacity={0.3}
      d="M704.987 418.176V497.36H785.678V417.759L704.987 418.176Z"
      fill="url(#paint5_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}
      opacity={0.3}
      d="M898.731 423.497H863.638V458.551H898.731V423.497Z"
      fill="url(#paint6_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}
      opacity={0.3}
      d="M940.151 423.497H905.058V458.551H940.151V423.497Z"
      fill="url(#paint7_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}
      opacity={0.3}
      d="M856.64 423.497H821.547V458.551H856.64V423.497Z"
      fill="url(#paint8_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path d="M940.15 478.999H850.403V487.39H940.15V478.999Z" fill="#D1D4FB" />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M940.151 491.771H827.948V494.365H940.151V491.771Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M850.478 463.022H829.008V465.615H850.478V463.022Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M891.928 463.022H870.457V465.615H891.928V463.022Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M933.347 463.022H911.876V465.615H933.347V463.022Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M857.64 495.989H821.547V498.583H857.64V495.989Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M940.151 500.177H827.948V502.771H940.151V500.177Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path d="M940.15 504.35H821.547V506.944H940.15V504.35Z" fill="#D1D4FB" />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M940.15 508.523H821.547V511.117H940.15V508.523Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M940.151 525.395H827.948V527.988H940.151V525.395Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M940.15 529.568H821.547V532.161H940.15V529.568Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M940.15 533.741H821.547V536.334H940.15V533.741Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M935.391 512.696H821.547V515.29H935.391V512.696Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M940.151 516.87H827.948V519.463H940.151V516.87Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
      <path
        d="M917.65 521.043H821.547V523.636H917.65V521.043Z"
        fill="#D1D4FB"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "soft-light" }}>
      <path
        d="M727.592 481.473C714.94 481.473 704.645 471.189 704.645 458.551C704.645 445.913 714.94 435.629 727.592 435.629C740.245 435.629 750.54 445.913 750.54 458.551C750.54 471.189 740.245 481.473 727.592 481.473ZM727.592 437.104C715.76 437.104 706.137 446.717 706.137 458.536C706.137 470.355 715.76 479.968 727.592 479.968C739.424 479.968 749.048 470.355 749.048 458.536C749.048 446.717 739.424 437.104 727.592 437.104Z"
        fill="#E0FFFF"
      />
    </g>
    <path
      d="M727.593 471.01C734.482 471.01 740.066 465.432 740.066 458.551C740.066 451.67 734.482 446.091 727.593 446.091C720.704 446.091 715.119 451.67 715.119 458.551C715.119 465.432 720.704 471.01 727.593 471.01Z"
      fill="white"
    />

    <path
      d="M797.251 419.575C798.259 413.176 793.882 407.172 787.476 406.165C781.07 405.159 775.059 409.53 774.051 415.929C773.044 422.329 777.42 428.332 783.826 429.339C790.233 430.346 796.243 425.974 797.251 419.575Z"
      fill="white"
    />
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "soft-light" }}>
      <path
        d="M700.975 396.402L702.646 393.854L711.717 401.797L710.33 403.735L700.975 396.402Z"
        fill="white"
      />
      <path
        d="M711.956 396.402L710.27 393.854L701.198 401.797L702.601 403.735L711.956 396.402Z"
        fill="white"
      />
    </g>
    <path d="M948.954 395.582H867.727V399.651H948.954V395.582Z" fill="white" />
    <path
      d="M775 246.141V289.136L826.498 289.572L827.191 244.758L775 246.141Z"
      fill="url(#paint9_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      d="M827.191 244.758L830.544 250.419L828.867 289.536L826.498 289.572L827.191 244.758Z"
      fill="url(#paint10_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      d="M784.202 260.649L788.958 253.768L814.671 275.32L810.717 280.562L784.202 260.649Z"
      fill="white"
    />
    <path
      d="M815.327 260.649L810.571 253.768L784.858 275.32L788.813 280.562L815.327 260.649Z"
      fill="white"
    />
    <path
      opacity={0.81}
      d="M321.389 771.41H145.191C137.355 771.41 130.94 765.148 130.758 757.321L127.46 612.957C127.278 604.875 133.783 598.213 141.892 598.213H325.343C333.471 598.213 339.994 604.911 339.776 613.03L335.821 757.394C335.603 765.203 329.206 771.41 321.389 771.41Z"
      fill="url(#paint11_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      d="M321.389 771.865H145.19C137.172 771.865 130.484 765.349 130.302 757.339L127.004 612.975C126.913 608.934 128.425 605.13 131.25 602.236C134.074 599.36 137.847 597.758 141.892 597.758H325.343C329.388 597.758 333.179 599.36 336.003 602.254C338.828 605.148 340.322 608.989 340.213 613.03L336.24 757.394C336.022 765.512 329.48 771.847 321.352 771.847L321.389 771.865ZM141.91 598.686C138.12 598.686 134.566 600.179 131.924 602.891C129.264 605.603 127.86 609.189 127.951 612.975L131.25 757.339C131.414 764.857 137.683 770.973 145.227 770.973H321.425C329.042 770.973 335.183 765.003 335.402 757.394L339.375 613.03C339.484 609.225 338.081 605.639 335.42 602.909C332.76 600.179 329.206 598.686 325.398 598.686H141.91Z"
      fill="#473DA2"
    />
    <path d="M267.649 627.756H174.985V631.724H267.649V627.756Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M221.308 637.385H174.985V641.353H221.308V637.385Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M221.308 645.43H174.985V649.398H221.308V645.43Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M263.367 645.43H226.502V649.398H263.367V645.43Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M249.681 653.476H174.985V657.444H249.681V653.476Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M201.573 661.521H174.985V665.49H201.573V661.521Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M253.017 685.676H207.04V689.644H253.017V685.676Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M258.319 669.585H174.985V673.553H258.319V669.585Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M239.094 677.631H174.985V681.599H239.094V677.631Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M205.144 685.676H174.985V689.644H205.144V685.676Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M221.308 693.722H174.985V697.69H221.308V693.722Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M188.27 701.767H174.985V705.735H188.27V701.767Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M241.954 701.767H193.736V705.735H241.954V701.767Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M253.017 709.576H207.04V713.544H253.017V709.576Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M205.144 709.576H174.985V713.544H205.144V709.576Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M221.308 717.622H174.985V721.59H221.308V717.622Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M188.27 725.667H174.985V729.635H188.27V725.667Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M241.954 725.667H193.736V729.635H241.954V725.667Z" fill="white" />

    <motion.g
      initial={{ rotate: 0 }}
      animate={{ rotate: 360 }}
      transformOrigin="50% 50%"
      transition={{ duration: "20", ease: "easeOut", repeat: "infinity" }}
    >
      <motion.path
        d="M822.78 340.272C696.042 200.181 479.734 189.355 339.643 316.093C199.551 442.831 188.726 659.139 315.464 799.23C442.202 939.322 658.51 950.147 798.601 823.409C938.692 696.671 949.518 480.363 822.78 340.272Z"
        stroke="#E1E4ED"
      />
      <motion.path
        d="M219.221 553.089C216.338 557.138 217.283 562.758 221.331 565.641C225.38 568.524 231 567.579 233.883 563.531C236.766 559.482 235.821 553.862 231.773 550.979C227.724 548.096 222.104 549.041 219.221 553.089Z"
        fill="url(#paint12_linear_1_2)"
      />
      <motion.path
        d="M254.264 454.878C254.264 460.467 249.726 464.999 244.132 464.999C238.538 464.999 234 460.467 234 454.878C234 449.29 238.538 444.758 244.132 444.758C249.726 444.758 254.264 449.29 254.264 454.878Z"
        fill="url(#paint13_linear_1_2)"
      />
    </motion.g>
    <path
      opacity={0.73}
      d="M437.692 420.259H367.407C361.747 420.259 357.109 415.785 356.922 410.131L355.367 363.951C355.165 358.023 359.918 353.117 365.852 353.117H439.104C445.023 353.117 449.776 358.009 449.589 363.922L448.178 410.103C448.005 415.756 443.367 420.259 437.692 420.259Z"
      fill="url(#paint14_linear_1_2)"
    />
   
    <path
      d="M386.145 369.719L368.818 389.774L386.462 404.736V397.025L376.25 388.192L385.727 377.488L386.145 369.719Z"
      fill="white"
    />
    <path
      d="M416.607 370.612L433.933 390.681L416.29 405.643V397.917L426.487 389.098L415.138 377.086L416.607 370.612Z"
      fill="white"
    />
    <path
      d="M389.919 404.736L405.013 371.518H412.114L395.018 404.736H389.919Z"
      fill="white"
    />
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d="M828.213 697.662L822.892 712.861C825.826 704.47 830.054 699.009 828.213 697.662ZM822.892 712.861L817.571 728.061C818.92 727.66 819.958 721.271 822.892 712.861ZM828.213 697.662L822.892 712.861C825.826 704.47 830.054 699.009 828.213 697.662ZM822.892 712.861L817.571 728.061C818.92 727.66 819.958 721.271 822.892 712.861ZM838.236 726.022L843.393 728.952L848.969 713.753L842.992 712.752C843.101 712.188 843.211 711.624 843.284 711.059C843.721 708.456 843.867 705.908 843.794 703.487L850.044 699.574L847.202 686.177L841.206 691.892C840.368 690.181 839.348 688.688 838.145 687.432C837.817 687.068 837.471 686.741 837.106 686.431L840.769 677.985L831.02 674.818L828.687 683.337C826.5 683.337 824.295 683.883 822.09 684.884L821.015 676.839L810.282 684.957L812.76 692.092C810.829 694.295 809.061 696.843 807.53 699.701L802.355 696.789L796.779 711.988L802.756 712.989C802.118 716.192 801.881 719.305 801.972 722.254L795.722 726.167L798.564 739.565L804.56 733.849C805.635 736.033 807.002 737.89 808.66 739.31L804.997 747.774L814.582 751.505L816.059 746.117L817.061 742.441C819.248 742.441 821.471 741.894 823.676 740.912L824.733 748.957L835.466 740.839L832.988 733.703C834.5 731.974 835.922 730.026 837.215 727.878C837.58 727.296 837.908 726.695 838.236 726.076V726.022ZM822.892 712.861C819.94 721.253 822.892 729.917 817.571 728.061C812.232 726.186 810.282 717.867 813.234 709.494C816.186 701.103 822.892 695.824 828.213 697.681C833.553 699.537 825.826 704.47 822.892 712.88V712.861ZM828.213 697.662L822.892 712.861C825.826 704.47 830.054 699.009 828.213 697.662ZM822.892 712.861L817.571 728.061C818.92 727.66 819.958 721.271 822.892 712.861Z"
      fill="url(#paint15_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d="M843.412 728.952L848.988 713.753L843.302 711.059L842.391 710.623L842.993 702.249L849.298 699.173L847.22 686.177L833.462 681.699L835.995 687.724L840.788 677.967L831.038 674.8L827.029 673.489L817.426 669.758L815.64 676.311L807.276 672.343L796.542 680.461L799.804 689.235L789.763 717.012L784.807 735.05L794.337 736.088L791.239 743.241L800.843 746.973L814.583 751.451L812.378 747.046L810.993 744.406L816.077 746.063L824.751 748.884L835.485 740.766L828.852 732.957L837.234 727.806L843.412 728.934V728.952ZM813.216 709.494C816.168 701.103 822.874 695.824 828.196 697.681L822.874 712.88L817.553 728.079C812.214 726.204 810.264 717.885 813.216 709.512V709.494Z"
      fill="url(#paint16_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d="M829.671 724.475L835.248 709.275L829.27 708.274C829.908 705.071 830.145 701.958 830.072 699.027L836.323 695.114L833.48 681.717L827.485 687.432C826.428 685.248 825.043 683.391 823.384 681.972L827.047 673.526L817.444 669.794L814.965 678.877C812.797 678.877 810.555 679.423 808.369 680.406L807.312 672.361L796.578 680.461L799.057 687.596C797.125 689.799 795.357 692.365 793.827 695.223L788.651 692.311L783.075 707.51L789.052 708.511C788.414 711.715 788.178 714.827 788.25 717.758L782 721.671L784.843 735.068L790.838 729.353C791.895 731.537 793.28 733.394 794.938 734.814L791.275 743.26L800.879 746.991L803.357 737.908C805.526 737.908 807.767 737.362 809.954 736.379L811.011 744.425L821.744 736.324L819.266 729.189C821.198 726.987 822.965 724.42 824.496 721.562L829.671 724.475ZM803.813 723.583C798.474 721.708 796.542 713.407 799.476 705.016C802.41 696.625 809.134 691.346 814.473 693.203C819.813 695.078 821.744 703.378 818.81 711.769C815.877 720.161 809.152 725.439 803.813 723.583Z"
      fill="url(#paint17_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }} opacity={0.5}>
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M850.044 699.574L836.304 695.096L830.054 699.009L843.794 703.487L850.044 699.574Z"
        fill="#601734"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "soft-light" }}>
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M835.485 740.784L821.726 736.306L819.248 729.171L833.006 733.649L835.485 740.784Z"
        fill="#B3D9FF"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }} opacity={0.5}>
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M823.366 681.972L830.91 684.138L833.462 681.699L838.455 683.337L840.787 677.985L827.029 673.508L823.366 681.972Z"
        fill="#601734"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }} opacity={0.5}>
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M803.339 737.926L810.537 740.912L809.936 736.379C809.936 736.379 806.054 738.418 803.339 737.908V737.926Z"
        fill="#601734"
      />
    </g>
    <g style={{ mixBlendMode: "multiply" }} opacity={0.5}>
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M804.451 696.734L816.569 703.141C816.569 703.141 818.319 700.793 819.685 699.847C819.685 699.847 816.514 686.486 804.433 696.734H804.451Z"
        fill="#601734"
      />
    </g>
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d="M533.048 247.009L530.405 185.758H610.714L607.416 246.846L533.048 247.009Z"
      fill="url(#paint18_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d="M530.405 185.758L528 189.362L530.405 247.009H533.048L530.405 185.758Z"
      fill="url(#paint19_linear_1_2)"
    />
    <path
      d="M557.084 197.99L544.474 196.643L546.205 238.618L557.084 237.544V233.212L550.779 233.357L550.05 200.975L557.084 201.175V197.99Z"
      fill="white"
    />
    <path
      d="M582.888 197.99L595.48 196.643L593.767 238.618L582.888 237.544V233.212L589.193 233.357L589.904 200.975L582.888 201.175V197.99Z"
      fill="white"
    />
    <defs>
      <pattern
        id="pattern0"
        patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
        width={1}
        height={1}
      >
        <use
          xlinkHref="#image0_1_2"
          transform="matrix(0.000830386 0 0 0.000833065 -0.217042 -0.110076)"
        />
      </pattern>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint0_linear_1_2"
        x1={758.279}
        y1={777.399}
        x2={379.632}
        y2={358.857}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#387FC4" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#E9F9FE" stopOpacity={0} />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint1_linear_1_2"
        x1={715.845}
        y1={495.002}
        x2={706.071}
        y2={488.042}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#000044" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#387FC4" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint2_linear_1_2"
        x1={340.23}
        y1={722.426}
        x2={313.36}
        y2={703.292}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#000044" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#387FC4" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint3_linear_1_2"
        x1={434.883}
        y1={199.531}
        x2={420.221}
        y2={189.089}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#000044" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#387FC4" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint4_linear_1_2"
        x1={691.589}
        y1={397.684}
        x2={955.772}
        y2={397.684}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#9D68C2" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#AEC2FF" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint5_linear_1_2"
        x1={745.332}
        y1={497.36}
        x2={745.332}
        y2={417.759}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#CCEDFF" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9D68C2" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint6_linear_1_2"
        x1={881.199}
        y1={458.551}
        x2={881.199}
        y2={423.497}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#CCEDFF" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9D68C2" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint7_linear_1_2"
        x1={922.604}
        y1={458.551}
        x2={922.604}
        y2={423.497}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#CCEDFF" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9D68C2" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint8_linear_1_2"
        x1={839.093}
        y1={458.551}
        x2={839.093}
        y2={423.497}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#CCEDFF" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9D68C2" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint9_linear_1_2"
        x1={775.002}
        y1={267.166}
        x2={827.191}
        y2={267.166}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#387FC4" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9EE3FC" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint10_linear_1_2"
        x1={826.498}
        y1={267.166}
        x2={830.544}
        y2={267.166}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#387FC4" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9EE3FC" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint11_linear_1_2"
        x1={127.465}
        y1={684.816}
        x2={339.781}
        y2={684.816}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#387FC4" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9EE3FC" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint12_linear_1_2"
        x1={233.883}
        y1={563.531}
        x2={219.221}
        y2={553.089}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#000044" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#387FC4" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint13_linear_1_2"
        x1={234}
        y1={449.269}
        x2={254.303}
        y2={449.413}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#000045" />
        <stop offset={0.475694} stopColor="#387FC4" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9EE3FC" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint14_linear_1_2"
        x1={355.36}
        y1={368.083}
        x2={449.77}
        y2={369.017}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#000045" />
        <stop offset={0.475694} stopColor="#387FC4" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#9EE3FC" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint15_linear_1_2"
        x1={817.113}
        y1={751.836}
        x2={828.569}
        y2={674.446}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#1852A0" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#067ED3" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint16_linear_1_2"
        x1={808.556}
        y1={749.836}
        x2={829.237}
        y2={672.944}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#1852A0" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#067ED3" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient
        id="paint17_linear_1_2"
        x1={799.409}
        y1={745.095}
        x2={811.6}
        y2={667.374}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#188DC1" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#06BFE7" />
      </linearGradient>
     
      
    </defs>
  </svg>
);
export default SvgComponent;
```

This is where the component is callled is app.

```
import SvgComponent from "@/HomeSvg";
import React from "react";

const page = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is contact</h1>
      <SvgComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;
```

Help me to debug why it is not working on Next.js.

Comment: I copy-pasted `SvgComponent` to one of my local projects and it's actually animating and some parts of it are rotating. Can you double check if there is a problem with your imports etc.

Comment: This could be due to server rendering, its running animations only once on server load.